# Getting application/json back from a Solr query

Tags: java, json, solr, jersey, jersey-client

I'm calling the Solr REST api using a Jersey client:

```
final ClientResponse resp =
  client().path(queryPath())
          .queryParam("q", query.getQuery())
          .queryParam("wt", "json")
          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
          .get(ClientResponse.class);

resp.getEntity(HttpResponse.class)
```

and when I run it I get:

```
A message body reader for Java class challenger.HttpResponse, and Java type class challenger.HttpResponse, and MIME media type text/plain; charset=UTF-8 was not found
```

Which suggests to me that the response is 'text/plain' rather than the 'application/json' requested.

Is it possible to get a real JSON response from a solr get query or do I need to marshal the JSON returned as text into an object myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wt param, should take care of JSON response format, as per [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Response+Writers#ResponseWriters-JSONResponseWriter). However, things can go wrong sometimes, as mentioned like JSON responses can be returned as plain text, with a change in solrconfig.xml. Please check that option also. Hope this helps you in identifying the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had no idea I had to look there.